# Fresh MinGW's support WinRT/UWP

Tags: c, windows-runtime, mingw, uwp, windows-store

I need to build some opensourse libs (eg, GStreamer) for Windows, so much so that they could be linked in UWP-application (new Windows 10 feature).

Now I superficially familiar with the UWP. One of the ways - use static libraries to use a third-party unmanaged C / C ++ code, and if there are no restricted functions (those Win32 API, that are not supported by UWP), the UWP application must build in MSVS 2015. But in libc/libstd++ can be a bunch of restricted Win32 API.

Caught a glimpse of that fresh mingw-w64 have support WindowsStore and something relating to WinRT. UWP - is the evolution of WinRT. Can someone explain what kind of support?

If anyone has experience with third-party c-libs use in UWP-application, please share, I would be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909139/can-windows-store-applications-be-built-with-mingw