# MSYS2 and Windows Runtime Library

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, msys2

I'm trying to compile a C/C++ library under msys2. The problem is, the library requires Windows Runtime Library ([WRL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438466.aspx)). And maybe more parts of Visual C++ Redistributable libraries. However I did not get that far in compilation process.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909139/can-windows-store-applications-be-built-with-mingw) about MSYS2 and WRL which suggests, that WRL is not supported yet. But its from late 2013. Maybe things have changed since.

Is any chance to make Visual C++ libraries (and headers) work with MSYS2?

Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest asking on the mingw-w64 mailing list if you don't get a good answer here.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Thank you, I'll try to.